# TypeError: invNum.next is not a function

Tags: node.js, promise

**I have tried this code :**

```
const invNum = require('invoice-number');

router.post('/checkout', async (req, res, next) => {

if (!req.session.cart) {
    return res.redirect('/pos/');
}

var saleList = Sale.find().sort({ _id: -1 }).limit(1); // removed (err, data)=>{} to simply view it is working tested already
var settings = await Setting.find({}); // removed try and catch to simply view it is working tested already
var ticketNumber;

ticketNumber = !saleList ? invNum.next('0000000') : invNum.next(saleList.ticket_number);

var sale = new Sale({
    ticket_number:ticketNumber,
    cart: req.session.cart,
    created_at: new Date()
});

sale.save((err, product) => {
    createReceipt(settings, req.session.cart, "receipts/"+ticketNumber+".pdf");
    req.session.cart = null;
    res.redirect('/pos/');
});

});
```

**I got this error:**

```
TypeError: invNum.next is not a function
```

The problem is with invNum.next().
invNum.next() is a Node.js module to generate invoice number sequentially installed from npm.

**Example:**

```
invNum.next('2017/08/ABC001')
// => 2017/08/ABC002
```

I have tried already suggestions from previous stackoverflow posts by trying Promises or await async function in order to get this code to work. Hopefully, you can help or suggest something. Thank you.

Comment: I am sure you must have done the require step somewhere for invNum , or is this missing

Comment: @Satya yes , i have var invNum = require('invoice-number');

Comment: Well,  your code is missing error handling.  There's no `try/catch` around the `await Setting.find({})` so if that has an error, you aren't catch the error and will get the `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`.  You also are ignoring the `err` parameter on your `sale.save()` callback which will cause  you to call `createReceipt()` even though the save failed.  To help you with `invNum.next()`, we will need some sort of reference to the doc for that and we will need to see how the `invNum` variable is populated (presumably you load some module).

Comment: @jfriend i have removed some part of the code to simplify for viewing. but they are err, parts.

Comment: If `invNum.next` is not a function (as the error says), then you aren't importing/loading that module correctly.

Comment: @jfriend00  I have : const invNum = require('invoice-number');

Comment: And, what does `console.log(typeof invNum.next)` output?  FYI, this is basic debugging steps to see why you are getting `TypeError: invNum.next is not a function`.

Comment: have already tried it is undefined. I m looking if there is problem in the module or ask the authors.  ty.

Comment: It's 25 lines of code.  You can step into it in the debugger and see what it's doing.  This doesn't have to be a black box.  You can debug this yourself (before you come here).   That's the beauty of NPM and the fact that you get all the source.

Comment: i am a new comer to node... ok i will take into account your suggestions. Anyway thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in version of invoice-number module. In the npm it is showing as 1.0.6 but in the GitHub repository it has 1.0.5 in the package.json file. 
https://github.com/amindia/invoice-number.

I have tested this module by taking from Github repository and it's working fine. 
Please take the source of this module from the given link it will works fine.

Comment: Solution npm install --save https://github.com/amindia/invoice-number was the solution!

Answer (score 0):

> I got this error:

`TypeError: invNum.next is not a function UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch()`

What is the output when you use the console.log on invNum?

Also use try catch and inside call invNum.next with await. Maybe something inside this function is throwing an error.

Edit: as jfriend00 says, if an plain text (like your "0000...") is working, probably the saleList is returning some error and you are not catching or treating the error.

Edit2: The last update on this NPM code is from 1 year ago and fewer people used this lib, probably is broken.

There is some part of the code from the index.js of the lib:

```
function _next (invoiceNumber) { 
if (!invoiceNumber) 
throw new Error('invoiceNumber cannot be empty') 
var array = invoiceNumber.split(/[_/:\-;\\]+/) 
var lastSegment = array.pop() 
var priorSegment = invoiceNumber.substr(0, invoiceNumber.indexOf(lastSegment))
var nextNumber = alphaNumericIncrementer(lastSegment)
return priorSegment + nextNumber}

var api = { next: _next} 

module.exports = api
```

Comment: have tried  invNum('000000') result expected 000001, i got the same error

Comment: @MichaelGEDION which is the output of the console.log(invNum)? Something is wrong with invNum

Comment: yes i got error with console.log(invNum('000000'))  invNum() is not a function.

Comment: let me try fix all the things jsfriend00 and you suggested. And will edit.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be some error in the module. I tried the below code snippet on RunKit 
https://runkit.com/embed/ws2lv1y38mt4

```
var invNum = require('invoice-number')
try{
 invNum.next('sdfsd1')
} catch(e){
console.log(e)
}
```

Getting the same error

Comment: @MichaelGEDION - Yeah, but the `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` is because you have no error handling.  Also, the whole module is about 35 lines of code in one file.  Just step into it and see what's going on or look at `invNum` and see if it has the right properties.